# React native use useEffect on navigation params

Tags: react-native

In my app, I have a `home` screen and `getData` screen, when user click a button in home screen the user will be directed to `getData` screen, and when data is retrieved from API, the user will be directed to `home` screen and see  the data retrieved. This will happen every time when user tries to get different data from the API.

Currently in my `getDataScreen.js`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    ...//data fetched, then direct to home page
    props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
        myData: myData
    }
})
```

In my `homeScreen.js`, I have a `modal` to show show the data, but the `modal` keep showing.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.navigation.getParam('myData')) {
        setData(myData);
        setModalShow(true);
    }
})

return (
    <View>
    <Button onPress={()=>{props.navigation.navigate('getData',{
        params:'params' // params to call API
    })}}/>
    <MyModal isVisible={modalShow}>.....</MyModal>
)
```

How can I make the `modal` shown only once when `myData` is detected?

Comment: please add your navigation to getData screen. It would be more helpful to solve the issue

Comment: @Ferin Patel added, just a simple button.

Comment: Is it necessary to navigate to other screen only for fetching the data.  You can fetch in same file also. is there any specific reason to navigate to getData screen and fetching the data

Comment: I am use the camera in getData screen, it reads a QR code and get the data then call the   API, I will try to fetch data in same screen.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, it seems that *useEffect* will be called after every state update. As you want to show modal only in case of a particular state update (let's say *data*), you must customize *useEffect* hook like

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.navigation.getParam('myData')) {
        setData(myData);
        setModalShow(true);
    }
}, [data]); // Only re-run the effect if data changes
```

You can get the reference from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).